# How to get the script interacting with a particular HTML element in a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a customized select drop down menu where suggestions are given when a user enters text in an input box.

This is the site from where I'm trying to extract the javascript code: http://www.redbus.in/

Here's the select drop down working in action:

[image]

I tried accessing the event listener for the corresponding input box through dev tools, but was unable to get the relevant script.

How can I get the corresponding script in this case? Are there any tricks/specific methods to get the script interacting with a particular HTML element?

PS: I'm a beginner in web development.

Comment: If you have loaded the scripts inside the DOM and they are not working.
Then you will have to pass that script tag to the eval(); function in javascript so that the script interacts/works with your html @theScorpion

Comment: @MalikAsifComsats I didn't get you. What I wanted know was the "code" which is interacting with the select box in image.

Comment: Pardon me. I don't know. @theScorpion

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome right click the element in the redbus.in page and select "Inspect element" this will bring up dev tools with that element selected.

Now under the "Sources" tab go to the "event listeners" 3rd along top-right of dev tools. Select the filter icon and choose "selected node only" (see screenshot):

[image]

Now look in the "keyup" section and click on the script. Then use the "{}" to beautify the code.

If the minified code is too much to crack. Then I would suggest using the twitter typeahead jQuery plugin.

You can apply this plugin to any input type="text" on your site like this:

```
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

I have have created a plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBQNQswXRG8kfFsq18Ak). The code is very easy to implement.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello @JDTLH9. Thanks for the help. I actually wanted that particular script, since I've been asked to.

Comment: And after that how do I get the particular function interacting with the "from" textbox?

Comment: @theScorpion I have added a plunk with code to achieve this a simpler way if you need something a little easier to digest ;)

Comment: thank you so much for the help. I upvoted your answer. 
I have one last query. In https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ I was trying to extract the script for the corresponding input box by this method, but I didn't get the script displayed on the page. It was showing some other code for that.

Comment: @theScorpion Thanks for the upvote. I am just curious if you have looked at the plunk I setup? This has the source code and uses the twitter typeahead.js code that is used in the examples you mention. If you look in the dev tools "sources" tab in the twitter.github.io domain you will see a "js" folder and this has an examples.js file and this is the exact same code that I put in the plunk's script.js file :)

Comment: I did see your plunk :) And I also found the example.js in sources tab. But it was not accessible by the steps you mentioned (selecting node only -> viewing script for keydown -> ..). By that method, I'm landing on the same statement highlighted in case of redBus.in

Comment: @theScorpion yes good point. I believe that the "event listener" is sending us to the method inside of the typeahead.bundle.js file. This is again in minified form and very hard to read. Most variable names have been shortened making it not readable at all. I saw the similarities in the code between that and the redbus.in script so it may be that they are using the twitter typeahead (very possible) they may just use a slightly different styling on the .tt-dropdown-menu element. Is there any need to understand the underlying script or can you just use typeahead,bundle.js same as the plunk?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was having exams. Yes. I need to understand the working of that selectbox which suggests cities. The one mentioned in https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ is pretty simple to understand. However, the script in http://www.redbus.in/ works differently. Try typing baaaangaloore, bengalare, bingalore, bingalore in the box. It always suggests Bangalore. This is not possible in the former script. Would accept your answer if you could explain its working :)

Comment: @theScorpion No problem :) Yes you are correct, I had not noticed that functionality before. It is a "fuzzy" matching algorithm that it will be using but I have not been able to find one that plugs nicely into the twitter typeahead. I will have another look over the next couple of days and see if I can update the plunk accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

IN Chrome DevTools the 3rd panel near 'Computed' is called 'Event Listeners'. You can see there all events and sources set on that node: id="txtSource"

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how do I get the specific function out of so many functions in http://www.redbus.in/js/libs.min.acf53a50.js  ?

Comment: You are probably looking for keyup event. Select that and click on the js file. Chrome will highlight the code. However that file is mintifyed and you will have a hell figure it out where it starts and end